# Rails: Controller code out of control

Tags: ruby-on-rails

First off, I must apologize for the punny title.

With that out of the way, I'm new to RoR and I am working on a small project that is slowly growing in size. One of the controllers is now a mess of logic that I would like to refactor it.

What I'm seeing from a multitude of questions/answers out there on this topic is mostly fragmented information on what I think is best practice. I'm having a hard time seeing the big picture. The sites for "where to put code?" have a high level information and miss the nitty-gritty.

Here's the question:

What's the best practice for refactoring code out of Controllers? (Locations, type of code)

Background: My app does not use a database, the code in the controller is mostly HTTP calls to external APIs based on params from a form, and a few lines of logic for creating arrays with fetched data for the view to consume. Some of these API calls depend on previously fetched info.

Thank you very much in advance!

MP

Comment: Sounds like you've managed to munge the responsibilities of controllers and models together. A controller is for passing information between models and views -- basically receiving input (params or values) or determining output (indicating which view to render in response). Everything else (business logic, including your HTTP calls) goes into your model. Anyhow, you're not really asking a specific programming question here. You might want to brush up with a Rails book at this point.

Answer (score 1):

Using the [single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle), I would create classes in `app/support/`, `app/services` to achieve the desired functionality that you have currently sitting in your controller. The controller should be about sending/receiving the requests, dish off the grunt work to your "support" classes. I found [this](https://blog.engineyard.com/2014/keeping-your-rails-controllers-dry-with-services) useful for this problem.

If you can justify that the functionality is concerned with a particular model and only that model, then use the model. I have seen the argument that you could use your model's for this logic, however my opinion is that a particular model should contain code only concerned with that model alone.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find the link before posting this answer, but something that will take you quite a ways is utilizing the helper files. This will get a lot of code out of your controllers and views.